# Htaccess redirect 5000+ urls to new relative url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I used to run a mediawiki with over 5000 articles. The path to the articles are like this:

http://www.example.com/index.php?title=Article

Now the articles are being transfered to a new and more modern website-setup. The new links to the articles will be like this:

https://www.example.com/wiki/article/

On Switch-Day I need a .htaccess file to automatically redirect the old urls to the new link but since there are over 5000 articles there needs to be relative commands. Any ideas here for the proper rewrite-rule?

Thank you

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please invest time to revise it and explain what exactly you mean by "relative commands".

Comment: Apart from that this appears to be a pretty straight forward task: you implement a pair of rewrite rules, one redirecting the old to the new pattern and the second one internally rewriting the new to the old pattern so that requests can get processed. You can see literally thousands of examples for that alone here on SO. So the question is: what is it you cannot do yourself? What is your actual and specific question besides "can someone please to my work for me"...